# PHP parse error in rss parse function

Tags: syntax, php4, feedparser

I have a client who needs a website urgently, but I have no access to information such as the control panel.

**PHP Version is 4.4 Which is a pain as I'm used to 5.**

The first problem is I keep getting:

```
Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')' in D:\hshome\*******\********\includes\functions.php on line 37
```

This is the function in question:

```
function read_rss($display=0,$url='') {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($url);
    $itemArr = array();

    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        if ($display == 0) {
            break;
        }

        $itemRSS = array(
            'title'=>$node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'description'=>$node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link'=>$node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue);

         array_push($itemArr, $itemRSS);

        $display--;
    }
    return $itemArr;
}
```

And the line in question:

```
'title'=>$node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
```

Comment: Please split your two questions into two questions. There is no imminent shortage in the database ;) and it's not very likely somebody will answer both your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP4 does not support object dereferencing.  So `$obj->something()->something` will not work.  You need to do `$tmp = $obj->something(); $tmp->something`...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in PHP 4.

Have to do something like

```
   $nodes = $node->getElementsByTagName('title');
   $item = $nodes->item(0);
   $value = $item->nodeValue,
```

Try it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain object calls in PHP 4. You're going to have to make each call separately to a variable and store it all.

```
$titleobj = $node->getElementsByTagName('title');
$itemobj = $titleobj->item(0);
$value = $itemobj->nodeValue;

...

'title'=>$value,
```

you'll have to do it on all those chained calls

As for .htaccess ... you need to talk to someone who controls the actual server. It sounds like .htaccess isn't allowed to change the setting you're trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down that line into individual variables. PHP 4 does not like -> following parentheses. Do this instead:

```
    $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $title = $title->item(0);
    $description = $node->getElementsByTagName('description');
    $description = $description->item(0);
    $link = $node->getElementsByTagName('link');
    $link = $link->item(0);

    $itemRSS = array(
        'title'=>$title->nodeValue,
        'description'=>$description->nodeValue,
        'link'=>$link->nodeValue);
```

The two variable declarations for each may be redundant and condensed, I'm not sure how PHP4 will respond. You can try to condense them if you want.

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocument is php 5 function.You cant use it.
you may need to use DOM XML (PHP 4) Functions